# ListView cannot be displayed

Tags: android, listview

this is my first time using the ListView and have have tried out many ways to make this workable. Firstly I used within the xml file under the  to specify the "android:entries" with a string-array, it displayed but I could not activate the onClickListener. The other method were similar to the one that I have, some were where I used "extend Acitvity" instead. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Basically, I want to use a customized textView row for each item on the list and show a toast for each clickable row. My problem is that the application would crash the moment I try to display this activity. I am not sure where the problem is as there isn't any syntax error. The error messages is ( Sorry, I would place a picture but I can't - new user ) :

- FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(edu.....)
- at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
- at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
- at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityTHread.java:139)
- at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
- at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
- at android.os.Looper.loop(Loooper.java:154)
- at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
- at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
- at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method java:511)
- at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
- at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygotaInit.java:551)
- at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
- Caused by:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams)...
- at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:471)
- at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:743)
- at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
- at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
- at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
- at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
- at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindows.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java ...)
- at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
- at edu.nyp.wonderful.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:14)
- at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
- at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
- at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityTHread.java:2158)
- ... 11 more lines ( I cannot show more to type out )

***Menu.java v***

```
package edu.nyp.wonderful;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        Log.d("Menu:", "after set content view");

        String[] items = { "Set Pins", "View Pins", "List of Pins", "Email Summary", "Edit Session's Info" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_row, R.id.menu_name, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("Menu:", "after setting adapter");
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

***menu.xml v***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu"
            android:textColor="#DC1700"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/separator1" 
         android:background="#000000" 
         android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="nothing" />

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

***menu_row.xml v***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDy="3"
    android:shadowDx="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Comment: Please add full logcat error.

Comment: added more of the error lines thanks

Comment: @user1661881 are you calling Menu (ListActivity) from some other activity.. Like using a button click or some thing?

Comment: Yes I am, I thought it was the previous activity as well, so I linked it to another activity with static display of a textview and it worked. =)

Comment: @user1661881, You haven't posted the relevant logcat details. Near the stacktrace of the crash, you should see a line that contains your package name. Please post that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, do you mean this?

-DB info:clos db, path = /data/data/....., key =M, handle ...
-shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa5228)

Comment: @user1661881, See my updated answer. Figured out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is the problem.

```
android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

It should be

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Fix it and check, report back if the problem persists.

**Update:** I can't believe I didn't see it earlier :P

You have a `TextView` inside the `Listview`. This is not possible. If you intend to use the "Empty View" Have them both inside a LinearLayout/FrameLayout. But the Listview cannot enclose the TextView, they should lie next to each other. Then, make sure you set the "Empty View" property in the "ListView" to the id of the Textview in this case `@android:id/empty` (please correct this as well)

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing it, but there's no difference. My reference is from the android application development for dummies pdf page 215 where they wrote down 'android:id="@+id/android:list"'

Comment: @user1661881, I can assure you the book is prolly wrong. Here's my [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) Also Please post the FULL logcat. I know you added more lines, but we need more, there should be more lines in Red, please post that.

Comment: yup, I have changed it according to yours, I was just cross-referencing, thanks =)

I have edited it and posted all the red lines, I can't access the last 11 lines, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        Log.d("Menu:", "after set content view");

        String[] items = { "Set Pins", "View Pins", "List of Pins", "Email Summary", "Edit Session's Info" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_row, R.id.menu_name, items);

        ListView lv  = getListView();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("Menu:", "after setting adapter");
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Tell me if it works...

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but sadly the activity could not be started again. Just to be clear its - 'ListView lv  = getListView();' that I entered. =)

Comment: ya, sorry i added two equal signs.. one more thing.. did you changed the listview name in xml to what said in the other answer. I assume you did it already. and there is a change in setting adapter also... You saw that??

Comment: Yup I did all that. But it still cannot run.